# Hiding one part of an ngFor in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a series of cards created using an ngFor loop in angular 5. I have added a button to the bottom to hide the card on click. The problem is that it hides all the cards not just the selected one. This is my click event:

```
 removeUserLikedProperty(property_id: string) {
    this._user.removeUserLikedProperty(property_id);
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    console.log(property_id)
  }
```

And this is where I try to hide it:

```
 <button class="button button-previous" (click)="removeUserLikedProperty(property?.property_id)">unlike</button>
```

and the for loop with the [hidden] biding:

```
     <section *ngIf="properties; else noItems">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let property of properties" >
        <div class="card" [hidden]="hidden">
          <div class="card_header" [routerLink]="['../../' + routes.Tenant.rent_property, property?.property_id]">
            <img src="{{property?.property_photos[0].image_url}}" class="image no-buttons property-card__carousel"
                 *ngIf="property?.property_photos?.length; else noImageUploaded">
            <ng-template #noImageUploaded>
              <img src="/assets/img/icons/camera.png" alt="" style="height: 250px; width: 100%; padding: 25px">
            </ng-template>
          </div>
          <div class="about">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="property-type" *ngIf="property?.description">{{property?.bedrooms?.length}} Bed
                  {{property?.property_type}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <div class="icons" *ngIf="property?.bedrooms?.length > 0 || property?.bathrooms">
                  {{property?.bedrooms?.length}}<img
                  src="/assets/img/icons/Double-Bed/Double-Bed.png" alt="" class="icon_default icon">
                  {{property?.bathrooms}} <img
                  src="/assets/img/icons/En-Suite-Bathroom/En-Suite-Bathroom.png" alt="" class="icon_default icon">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="address"> {{property?.street_number}}, {{property?.first_line_address}}
              <br>
              {{property?.city}},
              {{property?.post_code}}
            </p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="price">&pound;{{property?.rent_pcm}} pcm <br>
                  <span class="bills" *ngIf="property?.is_bills_included">including bills</span>
                  <span class="bills" *ngIf="!property?.is_bills_included">including bills</span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <p class="address"> Listed</p>
                <div class="date">{{property?.date_listed | date}}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p class="featured" *ngIf="property?.feature_tags"> {{property?.feature_tags}}</p>
            <button class="button button-previous" (click)="removeUserLikedProperty(property?.property_id)">unlike</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As mentioned, this hides all the cards instead of the clicked one. Anyone have any idea why? and how to change it?

Comment: They're all sharing the one property. Either make it a array of booleans you can index into, or break out a sub-component so each card can have its own state.

Comment: could you explain further the first technique?

Comment: The error would be easier to spot if you post the full html code (at least where you set your cards).

Comment: Please clarify what part of it you do not understand; arrays and indexing are pretty integral JS knowledge.

Comment: @Julien full html added

Comment: By the way you should consider making a card component. Also use [hidden] only if you have a good reason to. Otherwise use *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cards share the same `[hidden]=hidden` .So when you set `hidden` to `false`, all the cards disapear.

My recommandation would be smth like that :

```
<card *ngFor="let card of userCardList">
    ...
    <button (click)="removeCardFromUserList(card)">Remove</button>
</card>

removeCardFromUserList(card) {
    let index = userCardList.indexOf(card);
    userCardList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

That means that instead of having a list of cards and settings flags to say if they are hidden or visible, you can also have a list of visible cards. If you delete an item from this list it will automatically disapear on the page. If you had one  it will show. So no [hidden] or *ngIf needed in the view code for the card element.
So maybe keep your list with all the cards and have another list for the user.

The other solution is to have smth like `property.visible = false` since you deal with property objects. Just had an attribute in this object. Maybe much simplier in your case.

Comment: so how do i localise it to them individually?

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of Splicing from the list, You can have following object structure initially

userCardList = [{
'visibility': true,...
}, {
'visibility': true,...
},...]

just hide the card on clicking the card by setting the 'visibility' property to false.

<card *ngFor="let card of userCardList" *ngIf="card.visiblity">
    ....
    <p class="featured" *ngIf="property?.feature_tags"> 
        {{property?.feature_tags}}
    </p>
    <button (click)="card.visiblity = false">
        Remove
    </button> 
</card>
```